# How to set multiple HTTP cookies

Tags: http, session, cookies, session-cookies

I need to understand the format of HTTP cookie when used with secure and httponly flags.

By looking at Mozilla explanations, there is [this example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies):

> Set-Cookie: id=a3fWa; Expires=Wed, 21 Oct 2015 07:28:00 GMT; Secure;
>   HttpOnly

If I have multiple cookies, do they need multiple `set-cookie` and `secure` and `httponly` flags? Or is it written once? Please, clarify to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they need multiple `Set-Cookie` with `Secure` and `HttpOnly` flags, such as:

```
Set-Cookie: id=a3fWa; Expires=Wed, 21 Oct 2015 07:28:00 GMT; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: foo=Hello; Expires=Wed, 21 Oct 2015 07:28:00 GMT; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: bar=World; Expires=Wed, 21 Oct 2015 07:28:00 GMT; Secure; HttpOnly
```

According to [RFC6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-3), which defines Cookie and Set-Cookie header in HTTP:

> Origin servers SHOULD NOT fold multiple Set-Cookie header fields into a single header field.